# Do @NotNull annotations on getters have signifcant impacts on performance?

Tags: java, performance, null, getter, null-check

Random example: In the source code of one of my programs I have this method:

```
    public @NotNull Currency[] getCurrencies() {
        return this.currencies.values().toArray(new Currency[0]);
    }
```

Which, after being compiled, gets turned into the following by my IDE (Intellij):

```
    @NotNull
    public Currency[] getCurrencies() {
        Currency[] var10000 = (Currency[])this.currencies.values().toArray(new Currency[0]);
        if (var10000 == null) {
            $$$reportNull$$$0(4);
        }

        return var10000;
    }
```

`this.currencies` refers to `private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Currency> currencies = new ConcurrentHashMap();` - which means that only via means of reflection or cosmic rays causing bit flips, the method `getCurrencies()` could ever return `null`.

- Should I - in such cases where there is no chance for a `null` being returned - forgo the usage of the `@NotNull` annotation?
- Does the annotation even have significant impact on performance, or do the benefits of having the annotation outweigh the performance impact?

Thank you

/edit:
I am using the annotation package `org.jetbrains.annotations`

Answer (score 1):

`@NotNull` is not an annotation for your compiler. The compiler might *use* this annotation and do some additional checks. But `@NotNull` is an annotation for the humans reading your code that the compiler *checks*. Of Java's many problems, the biggest by far is the prevalence of unchecked `null` values floating around everywhere. In an otherwise statically-typed language, any variable anywhere in your program may simply not exist and violate every guarantee the type checker could otherwise provide.

Kotlin has proper nullable types. Recent versions of Scala have (opt-in) nullable types. Even new versions of C# have nullable types. In Java, `@NotNull` should be considered part of your function's contract, almost part of its type. You're not saying "hey, compiler, check if this is `null`". You're saying "I guarantee this function will never return `null`" and the compiler is checking it, in the same way that declaring a return type of `String` is making a guarantee that you're returning a `String`. Removing the `@NotNull` annotation because you're sure it's right is tantamount to changing all of your return types to `Object` because you know in your head what types the functions return. If you think

```
String getName(String prefix) { ... }
```

looks better than

```
Object getName(Object prefix) { ... }
```

then you should think

```
@NotNull String getName(@NotNull String prefix) { ... }
```

looks even better. It's a stronger guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

Having a `null` check on your getter is a bit strange. At the time you call the getter your object is already in a state it shouldn't be in. You probably want to have the `@NotNull` on the parameter for your setter or constructor instead.

What you can do is write a JavaDoc for your `getCurrencies`.

```
/**
/* @return An array of currencies. Never null.
*/
public Currency[] getCurrencies() {}
```

But it's very uncommon to document that a method doesn't return `null`. Not returning `null` should be the gold standard and if a method can return `null` it should be documented, not the other way around. Also I wouldn't expect a getter that returns a set of data (arrays, lists etc.) to return `null`. Instead return an empty object.